# How to delete a fk record in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My goal is to delete the fk record related with the record of the given id in the endpoint.

my url

```
path('car-pricing/<uuid:car_id>/', car_pricing),
```

my model

```
class Pricing(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name="pricings", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In other words I want to delete a specific `Pricing` record given the id of a `Car` in my endpoint.

By requesting with an id of a `Car` record I can get more than one `Pricing` records.

**Is it somehow possible to choose to delete a specific `Pricing` based on the id?**

my view(here, I do not know how to deal with delete function)

```
elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        pricing_data = request.data

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here the requested data is an empty QueryDict and it is ok, since there is no way to give requested data to a delete action in django rest framework

Comment: CASCADE will do all the work.

Comment: @IvanStarostin please could you be more specific?

Comment: `on_delete=models.CASCADE` when a car is deleted all the linked pricings will be deleted too.

Comment: I know that and I have implement it, look at my model part. I want to delete a pricing record not the car record

Comment: So this does not make sense to make requests with car_id. Unless you know how to choose particular pricing from many (and this still makes sense in terms of business logic).

Comment: It makes sense because I want to check the pricings for a particular car and not for all cars. This is the issue , how to choose a particular pricing from many.

Comment: It does not make sense to _"delete a car but not delete a car and delete a price but not clear which out of many"_, so fix your url pattern and requests to `car-pricing/<uuid:pricing_id>/` and do delete specific price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to delete specific object you must have specific filter which will return just one object. As far as I see you have `one to many` relation between `Car` and `Pricing` models, so you can't delete a specific pricing by filtering just `car` field (because car can be connected to more than one pricing object). When you want to delete specific row from table with some filters you should have constraint on that table and those filters to return just one row. However you can delete records of pricing by using `Pricing.object.filter(car_id=car_id).delete()` but in this case you will delete all the pricing objects which is related to that car. If you change the `path('car-pricing/<uuid:car_id>/', car_pricing),` to `path('car-pricing/<uuid:car_id>/<int:pk>/', car_pricing)` you can delete specific record by filtering as `Pricing.objects.filter(pk=pk, car_id=car_id).delete()` or by just using `path('car-pricing/<int:pk>/', car_pricing)` and `Pricing.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()` you can delete specific pricing object because `pk` of this table is a unique field and also is a constraint on that table.